# override sbt internal dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, log4j

sbt contains internal dependency - util logging:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/util-logging_2.10/1.2.0

and util logging dependency contain `org.apache.logging.log4j » log4j-api`:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.8.1

the problem is that project download dependencies behind the proxy, and proxy does not contain 2.8.1 version of log4j-api(because of vulnerabilities), but proxy contains 2.17.1 version of `log4j-api`. So I want to use 2.17.1 version instead of 2.8.1. Is there an opportunity to do it. I mean I've got and error during dowloading dependencies:

```
module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1
```

Even I don't want to download `org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1` because it leads to error during build

scala 2.10.4

sbt 1.2.0

Comment: Can you move to a newer version of sbt? Latest is 1.6.2.

Comment: @SethTisue no I can not move to newer sbt, project is very old

Comment: If you want security, just upgrade everything: SBT, Scala..

Comment: Seconded. Tell your bosses that they can choose security, and they can choose to cling to ancient versions of software, but they can't choose both at the same time.